# Glue Job Writes Multiple Partitions to the Same File

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I'm trying to write a glue job that converts multiples csv files to separate json files using each row of the csv for a file. When the job finishes, the correct number of files show up in s3, but some are empty and some have multiple json objects in the same file.

After I apply the mapping, this is how I create the partitions and write the files:

```py
numEntities = applyMapping1.toDF().count()
partitions = applymapping1.repartition(numEntities)
partitions.toDF().write.mode("ignore").format("json").option("header", "true").save("s3://location/test")
```

Using this, some files are created as a json file that has 2 objects one after the other, some are correct, and some are empty.

Is there any way I can ensure that each partition creates a separate file with only its data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [Partitioner](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.html) behind `repartition` does *not exactly* do what you intend:

It created as many partitions as you requested - so far so good. But it didn't distribute the rows into only one of the partitions each. That may be due to the logic in [HashPartitioner](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/HashPartitioner.html) having calculated the same hash value for more than one of the rows.

As an alternative to `repartition.save...` you could use `foreachPartition` and then iterate over each row, saving it to a file (e.g. under `/tmp`) and uploading it to S3. I wouldn't `repartition` before doing that because the UDF that will be executed from `foreachPartition` is rather expensive, so you should minimize the number of UDF invocations.

Here is an example that worked for me. It's written in Scala, though:

```
dynamicFrame.
  repartition(1).
  toDF().
  foreachPartition(p => {
    val out = new BufferedOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/temp.xsv.gz")))
    p.foreach(r => {
      val row = ...
      out.write(row)
    })
    val s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1).build()
    val tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(s3).build()
    val rq = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, new File("/tmp/temp.xsv.gz"))
    tm.upload(rq).waitForCompletion()
  })
```

Comment: Looking into it, not sure how I can write to s3 in the function I pass to foreach. I've tried both the spark context and boto3 and neither can be serialized to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like I got it working. From [rowing-ghoul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405613/rowing-ghoul)'s answer I ended up using a foreach to process the data, but because of how spark works, I had to send the data to s3 after. I also had to use an accumulator to store the json strings in the foreach.

```
class ArrayAccumulator(AccumulatorParam):
  def zero(self, value):
    return []
  def addInPlace(self, val1, val2):
    val1.extend(val2)
    return val1
jsonAccumulator = sc.accumulator([], ArrayAccumulator())

def write_to_json(row):
  # Process json
  jsonAccumulator += [json]

mappedDF = applymapping1.toDF()
mappedDF.foreach(write_to_json)

count = 0
for x in jsonAccumulator.value:
  s3.Object('bucket-name', 'test/' + str(count) + '.json').put(Body=x)
  count += 1
```